Using breakpoints for gradient colour of cells in a data table
I am in the process of creating a heat map using a data table, but I am encountering issues with setting the breakpoints correctly.
Here are the desired color coding rules for the heat map:
Values greater than 0.12 should be displayed in green, with 0.12 representing the minimum and the maximum value of the data frame.
Values between 0.12 and 0.05 should transition from yellow to red.
Values below 0.05 should transition from red to dark red, with 0.05 representing the maximum of this range and the minimum value of the data frame.
Currently, the heat map is utilizing the global minimum and maximum values of the data frame for color scaling, which is problematic. For instance, if the global maximum is 0.10 and the minimum is 0.03, the heat map incorrectly ranges from green to yellow to red instead of following the specified color transitions.
e.g of data frame
   HM = {
          ['A', 0.10, 0.3, 1.0],
          ['B', 0.9, 0.2, 0.2],  
          ['C', 0.8, -0.1, 0.1], 
          ['D', 0.7, -0.2, -0.3], 
          ['E', 0.6, -0.3,-0.5]  
         }

   output$dt_table <- renderDT({

   colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))

    dtable <- datatable(
      HM,
      rownames = FALSE,
      extensions = 'Scroller',
      selection = list(mode = 'none'),
      options = list(
      initComplete = JS(
        "function(settings, json) {",
        "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#2864D6', 'color': 'white'});",
        "}"
      ),
      dom = 't',
      scrollX = TRUE,
      pageLength = 100,
      columnDefs = list(
        list(className = 'dt-center', width = '20%', targets = "_all")
      )
    )
  )

     x <- unlist(HM)
     for (column in names(HM)) {
      brks <- quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = 500), na.rm = TRUE)
      RGB <- colfunc(length(brks))
      clrs <- apply(RGB, 1, function(rgb) {
      sprintf("rgb(%s)", paste(round(rgb, 0), collapse = ","))
    })

    dtable <- dtable %>%
      formatStyle(column, backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
  }

  dtable
}


Please provide us with a reproducible example. Btw. is there a particular reason why you are trying to implement it with library(DT)? I'd take a look at e.g. plotly.

  output$dt_table <- renderDT({
    # Initialize the datatable
    datatable(
      H2,
      rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(
        dom = 't',
        scrollX = TRUE,
        pageLength = 10,
        columnDefs = list(
          list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")
        ),
        # Add JavaScript to apply the colors
        drawCallback = JS("
          function(settings) {
            var api = this.api();
            api.rows().every(function() {
              var data = this.data();
              var rowIdx = this.index();
              $(this.node()).find('td').each(function(colIdx) {
                if (colIdx > 0) { // Skip the first column
                  var value = parseFloat(data[colIdx]);
                  var cell = this;
                  var color = '';

                  if (isNaN(value)) {
                    color = 'white';
                  } else if (value > 0.12) {
                    var greenValue = Math.round(255 * (1 - (value - 0.12) / (0.88)));
                    color = 'rgb(' + greenValue + ', 255, ' + greenValue + ')';
                  } else if (value >= 0.05) {
                    var yellowValue = Math.round(255 * ((value - 0.05) / 0.07));
                    color = 'rgb(255, ' + yellowValue + ', 0)';
                  } else {
                    var redValue = Math.round(255 * ((0.05 - value) / (0.05 + 0.02)));
                    color = 'rgb(255, ' + redValue + ', ' + redValue + ')';
                  }

                  $(cell).css('background-color', color);
                }
              });
            });
          }
        ")
      )
    )   }) }



  HM <- dbGetQuery(con, heat_map)
  # HM$PRED_AE_KR_0 <- as.numeric(HM$PRED_AE_KR_0)
  # HM$PRED_AE_KR_15 <- as.numeric(HM$PRED_AE_KR_15)
  # HM$PRED_AE_KR_30 <- as.numeric(HM$PRED_AE_KR_30)
  
  colnames(HM) <- c("STF Discount", "0%", "15%", "30%")

  HM <- na.omit(HM)
  HM$"0%"<- as.numeric(HM$"0%")
  HM$"15%" <- as.numeric(HM$"15%")
  HM$"30%" <- as.numeric(HM$"30%")

  HM$"STF Discount" <- as.character(HM$"STF Discount")

  HMCAL(HM)

  lowest <- max(HM$"30%")
  highest <- min(HM$"0%")

  H2 <- HM %>%
    select("0%", "15%", "30%")

  
  green_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#ADFF2F", "#7FFF00", "#00FF00"))
  yellow_to_red_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#FFA500", "#FFD700", "#FFFF00"))
  red_to_dark_red_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#FF4500", "#FF0000"))


  output$dt_table <- renderDT({
    # Define color functions for each region

    dtable <- datatable(
      HM,
      rownames = FALSE,
      extensions = 'Scroller',
      selection = list(mode = 'none'),
      options = list(
        initComplete = JS(
          "function(settings, json) {",
          "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#2864D6', 'color': 'white'});",
          "}"
        ),
        dom = 't',
        scrollX = TRUE,
        pageLength = 100,
        columnDefs = list(
          list(className = 'dt-center', width = '20%', targets = "_all")
        )
      )
    )
    
    # print(is.numeric(unlist(H2)))
    # x <- as.numeric(unlist(H2))
    # x <- H2[[column]]
    x <- round(unlist(H2), digits = 3)
    for (column in names(H2)) {
      print(x)
      max_val <- max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
      min_val <- min(x, na.rm = TRUE)
      cell_colors <- sapply(x, function(value) {
        if (value >= 0.12) {
          normalized_value <- (value - 0.12) / (max_val - 0.12)
          green_palette(100)[round(normalized_value * 99) + 1]
        } else if (value >= 0.05) {
          normalized_value <- (value - 0.05) / (0.12 - 0.05)
          yellow_to_red_palette(100)[round(normalized_value * 99) + 1]
        } else {
          normalized_value <- (value - min_val) / (0.05 - min_val)
          red_to_dark_red_palette(100)[round(normalized_value * 99) + 1]
        }
      })
      
      print(x)

      dtable <- dtable %>%
        formatStyle(column, backgroundColor = styleEqual(x, cell_colors))%>% 
        formatPercentage(columns = 2:4, 1)
    }
    
    dtable
  })
})   })


